# BPEL: how to solve "end point reference not available..."error

Tags: web-services, glassfish, bpel

I am performing Web Services Orchestration with BPEL, using Netbeans 6.7.1 and Glassfish server. In my simple BPEL process, I have a sequence of receive->assign->invoke->assign->reply activities, where the invoke is a synchronous one to an operation on a remote web-service (from http://www.webservicex.net). I have successfully deployed my service as a JBI module (in a composite application) and when I try to test it using some input values for the input message of the operation I get the following error message:

....

Caused by: BPJBI-6018: EndPoint Reference is not available from the JBI corresponding to the service name {http://enterprise.netbeans.org/bpel/SimpleInvocation/simpleInvocation}plGlobalWeather and endpoint name GlobalWeatherSoapRole_partnerRole

SimpleInvocation is my BPEL process and GlobalWeatherSoap is the portType in the remote WDSL of the remote service for which the operation I wanted to invoke is defined.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It most likely that you do not have connection from Glassfish server to that webservuce. You can login to host where your Glassfish server is runnig and do a telnet to  www.webservicex.net on port 80. This will confirm if you have connectivity or not.

Comment: Thanks. The error was because of the connectivity, and there was a connection missing from the output of my BPEL module to the WSDL interface to the remote partner link. (sorry but I am unable to up-vote though.)